# stability of solution of ode

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory

I'm new to ODE and currently working on an optimal control problem. I'm trying to calculate the trajectories of a wheeled robot. I can steer it only continously but in theory it makes also sense to allow $L^1$ steerings, because the initial value problem has also a local solution for them (existencetheorem of caratheodory).

My dynamical system is nonholonomic with smooth and Lipschitz vectorfields $P_1,\dots,P_l: R^3 \rightarrow R^3$ and controls $u:[0,T]\rightarrow R^l$

$\dot{p}(t)=\sum^l_{i=1}P_i(p(t))u_i(t)$

I want to show that it is for practical applications not relevant if I allow also $L^1$ functions, since $C^0([0,T],R^l)$ is dense in $L^1([0,T],R^l)$.

I found a stability theorem in the book of Bartels (3x9 Numerik 20.4) which states the fact that a small variation of continous dynamical systems results in a small variation of the solution trajectory, but I can't apply it to my problem since the dynamical system with the $L^1$ steering is not continous.

Does anyone know a more general result that I can use?

Comment: Do you still need an answer? I checked the book out and Satz 20.4, p.174 is just a continuous dependence theorem. Seems like it'd hold easily if you assume $f, \overline f \in \mathcal L^1([0,T]\times \mathbb R)$, perhaps in an "almost everywhere" fashion if you assume the inequalities do.